# Why HtmlHelper would skip validation attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

Why `@Html.TextBoxFor` and other helpers would skip jquery.validation attributes and create elements without those? Am I missing some references or something? It's MVC 3.0 project.

If I add them manually like that:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, 
       new { data_val="true", data_val_required="Need that field" })
```

then unobtrusive validation works. But it's suppose build elements and put those attributes  based on Model's `DataAnnotations`. Model is there, textbox inside of a form body, and still doesn't work. What could it be?

upd: `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` set to `true` in `web.config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure these two lines in your web.config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: No problem - glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

For unobtrusive validation to work you need to ensure that `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is set to `true` in your `Web.config` and that you have included these 3 scripts:

- jQuery (~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js)
- jQuery Validate (~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js)
- the MVC plugin for unobtrusive client validation with jQuery Validate (~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js).

Answer (score 0):

1.if the text box is loading via ajax, it's may not be parsed for Unobtrusive validation.
2.check rendered html if there is a data-val-required attribute for the text box to determine if it's a server side or client side problem.