# HTML Helper TextBoxFor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, validationsummary

I have my cshtlm page with the next code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Optional", "ConfigurationSilo2", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "storeDataForm" }))
{          
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Height)  

    <div align="right">
        <input type="submit" id="Avanti" value="@ViewRes.ConfigurationString.buttonNext" name="@ViewRes.ConfigurationString.buttonNext" />
    </div>
}
```

My html generated code is:

```
<form action="/ConfigurationSilo2/Optional" id="storeDataForm" method="post">

     <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Height must be a number." data-val-required="The Height field is required." id="Height" name="Height" type="text" value="0" />          
    <div align="right">
        <input type="submit" id="Avanti" value="Next" name="Next" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my model code class:

```
public class Spondina
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public float UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public float TotalCost { get; set; }
}
```

why are there tags **data-val data-val-number data-val-required**  in my input tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the MVC validation kicking in. Do you have data annotations on your model? I'm guessing that the `Height` property has `[Required]` against it? The attributes are used by the unobtrusive client validation framework. Here is the line within the input helper that adds those tags:

```
tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));
```

The `HtmlHelper` has a `ClientValidationRuleFactory`, which is initialized in the constructor of `HtmlHelper` with, amongst other things, a `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider`, which examines the metadata of your model and applies appropriate validation rules in cases of numeric types in your model, for example. If you have client validation enabled and numeric types in your model, e.g. `Height` as an int, the helpers will inject unobtrusive client validation into those inputs during render.

Comment: If you don't want to enable client-side validation, you can set the "ClientValidationEnabled" and "UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" appSetting entries to "false".

Comment: No, I don't have any attribute for **Height**.

Comment: Updated my answer with more of the underlying reasons

Comment: @Erik Schierboom: how and where should I set those appSetting?

Comment: @gorgonzola You can find them in the Web.config file of your project.

Comment: @gorgonzola see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959349/why-htmlhelper-would-skip-validation-attributes